# Double parenthesis around expression in While loop

Tags: c, while-loop, char, eof, fgetc

I was attempting to read a file as such:

```
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) { ... }
```

And was not stepping into the loop. Why doesn't this code work?

I realized the error was failing to place the wrapping parenthesis before the not equals comparison to `EOF`, as such:

```
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { ... }
```

However, I don't understand why the first conditional doesn't work. I tested it with
`printf("%d", c = fgetc(fp) != EOF)`, and that returns `1`. So the issue must be something to do with the conditional being wrapped inside of `(...)` parenthesis, which would seem to make it be evaluating to `while ( (1) )`.

I bet I am misunderstanding RE: the operator association order, but do not know for certain the root of the error here.

Comment: I’m not sure what would explain the difference with `printf`, but `char` is the wrong type for `c` either way; `fgetc` returns an `int`, because `EOF` shouldn’t conflict with any `char`.

Comment: It's not the double parentheses that make a difference, it's the fact that `!=` has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=`.

Comment: An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, which means that c = fgetc(fp) will be whatever value that ascii character happens to have. Try to do the assignment outside of the condition.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. It steps into the loop for me, with `c=1`, until it hits EOF at which point it exits with `c=0`. How did you determine that the loop wasn't entered?

Comment: @thatotherguy It is my mistake. I was printing the character inside the loop to show what was being read. However, I was printing it as a `char`, when in fact it was evaluating to an `int`, as mentioned. So I suppose I was seeing garbage output or nothing at all. Not a great way to test, admittedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition expression depends on the precedence of operations.

In fact in this while loop

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) { ... }
```

you may remove a pair of external parentheses like

```
while ( c = fgetc(fp) != EOF ) { ... }
```

because they do not change the semantic of the condition.

Now according to the operator precedence this loop looks like

```
while ( c = ( fgetc(fp) != EOF ) ) { ... }
```

The expression in the inner parentheses `( fgetc(fp) != EOF )` is evaluated either to integer 0 or 1 as a logical expression.

So as result you will get either

```
while ( c = 1 ) { ... }
```

if the expression  `( fgetc(fp) != EOF )` evaluates to the logical true or

```
while ( c = 0 ) { ... }
```

if the expression evaluates to the logical false.

Pay attention to that the variable `c` shall be declared as having the type `int` because it is the return type of the function `fgetc` that can return the value `EOF`.

```
int c;
while ( ( c = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) { ... }
```

Otherwise you will compare an object of the type `char` and an object of the type `int` that is defined as the macro `EOF`.

However in general the type `char` can behave as the type `unsigned char` (depending on a compiler option or by default) and in this case due to the integer promotion an object of the type `char` (that stores a non-negative value) will never be equal to `EOF` that is defined usually like `-1`. (or like some other negative value).